# SQL literal value that is alternative to NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Are there other special literal values besides NULL in SQL / PostgresQL?

NULL is nice in that we can interpret NULL as the concept of "nothing"  (i.e. missing, not available, not asked, not answered, etc.), and data columns of any type can have NULL values.

I would like another value that I can interpret as representing another concept (here the idea of "everything"), in the same result set.

Is there another special value that I can return in a query, which like NULL doesn't type conflict?

Basically anything that doesn't throw  `ERROR:  For 'UNION', types varchar and numeric are inconsistent` in this toy query:

```sql
select 1    as numeral, 'one' as name UNION ALL 
select 2    as numeral, 'two' as name UNION ALL 
select NULL as numeral, NULL  as name UNION ALL 
select -999 as numeral, -999  as name UNION ALL  -- type conflict
select '?'  as numeral, 'x'   as name            -- type conflict
```

Here,

- `-999` doesn't work as its type conflicts with varchar columns
- `'~'` doesn't work as its type conflicts with numeric columns
- `NULL` doesn't work as it needs

More specifically here's my actual case, counting combinations of values and also include "Overall" rows in the same query.  Generally I won't know or control the types of columns A, B, C in advance.  And A, B, or C might also have NULL values which I would would still want to count separately.

```
SELECT A, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ?, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY 1
```

and get a result set like:

| A | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 10 |
| (all) | 20 |

```
SELECT B, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ?, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY 1
```

and get a result set like:

| B | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 2 |
| 'Circle' | 3 |
| 'Line' | 5 |
| 'Triangle' | 10 |
| (all) | 20 |

Comment: You could [create a type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html).  Could you explain the problem you're trying to solve with this more concretely? There might be another way.

Comment: How do you intend on consuming the result of this query? Can you cast every column to varchar, that would allow them to be unioned.

Comment: @Schwern I'm trying to get a count of each unique value plus a count of all values of a column in the same query, in a simple generic way that I can repeat for a wide variety of data columns, and don;t know the data type for any column in advance

Comment: @stu I could, but then `"12"` would sort alphabetically before `"2"`

Comment: No. And by the way, you say the `NULL` means *missing, not available, not asked, not answered*. It is none of those things: `NULL` means "unknown".

Comment: Well a column, be it in a regular table or derived table can only be a single data type so you can only union the result of two queries with the same or implicitly castable types; there is no other concept of NULL afaik. I don't know postgres well enough if it has a similar concept to sql server's *variant* type.

Comment: @Schwern Is there a variation of `::!` which casts a value to whatever type isnecessary to not generate an error, e.g. `SELECT -999::!void` would work with int, float, varchar, etc.?

Comment: You won't be able to achieve that, because SQL is a strongly typed language. Perhaps add another column to the result set that indicates from which part of the `UNION ALL` a row comes.

Comment: "*also include "Overall" rows in the same query*" - are you maybe looking for a ROLLUP?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Yes!  First, that's exactly the concept I need, and is almost perfect.  But trying it now it returns NULL to represent both NULL and overall.  Is there a way to differentiate which rows are a count of NULL values and which are rollups?

Comment: Check out the [grouping()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-GROUPING-TABLE) function

Comment: Your example union queries are all for the same table, so it seems like this would be solved by a group by. Are they supposed to be unioning queries from two different tables? As for sorting, it's going to be tricky to sort a set of unknown types in a meaningful way. You might want to do that in a programming language after you've fetched the results.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Your comments ( "Use ROLLUP to get subtotals, and GROUPING to differentiate true NULLs from subtotal placeholders.") are the answer to the question I wish I knew to ask originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function `CAST` to convert the format to `VARCHAR` to be considered as string.

Comment: Casting to strings is actually really a good fit in practice.  We can use a special string for OVERALL and coalesce nulls to empty strings, both of which you can use in subsequent joins.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**   Thanks to the comments above, I should completely rephrase this question as "How to COUNT/GROUP BY with ROLLUP using multiple columns of mixed/arbitrary/unknown types, and differentiate true NULL values from ROLLUP placeholders?"

The correct answer I believe is provided by @a_horse_with_no_name: use `ROLLUP` with `GROUPING`.
Below is is just me drafting that more completely with a revised example:

This toy example has an integer and a string

```
WITH table AS (
    select 1    as numeral, 'one' as name UNION ALL 
    select 2    as numeral, 'two' as name UNION ALL 
    select 2    as numeral, 'two' as name UNION ALL 
    select NULL as numeral, NULL  as name UNION ALL
    select NULL as numeral, NULL  as name UNION ALL
    select NULL as numeral, NULL  as name 
)
select name, numeral, COUNT(*), GROUPING_ID() 
FROM table
GROUP BY ROLLUP(1,2)
ORDER BY GROUPING_ID, name, numeral ;
```

It returns the following result:

| numeral | name | count | grouping_id | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | 3 | 0 | both are true NULLs as grouping is 0 |
| 1 | one | 1 | 0 |  |
| 2 | two | 2 | 0 |  |
| NULL | NULL | 3 | 1 | first is a true NULL, second is a ROLLUP |
| 1 | NULL | 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | NULL | 2 | 1 |  |
| NULL | NULL | 6 | 3 | both NULLs are ROLLUPs |